# Getting json object

Tags: json, get

first time using json.  I currently send a postcode to a php page, and try to store the result as json:

```
    $("#make_ajax_call").click(function()
    {
        var form_postcode = $("#postcode").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'mapping-ajax.php',
            data: { postcode: form_postcode},
            success: function(data)
            {
                var jsonObject = data;
                var trimmedpostcode = jsonObject.trimmedpostcode;
                alert(jsonObject);
                alert(jsonObject.trimmedpostcode);
                $('#result').html(data);
                //alert('Load was performed.');
            }
        });
    });
```

On the other end I use a php function `echo json_encode($return_array);`

The two alerts give me:

```
{"trimmedpostcode":"CO125WL","success":true,"outputstring":"CO125WL<br\/>"}
```

and

```
Undefined
```

How come the second one doesn't return "CO125WL"? Do I need to tell javascript its a json object somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

This is how I pull in my json information in Javascript with an ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You got it. You need to call:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
```

That will parse the JSON into a JavaScript Object.

Comment: Works great, thanks! You answered too quickly for me to accept as an answer though, I will as soon as stackoverflow lets me. `var obj = JSON.parse(data);
     alert(obj);
     alert(obj.trimmedpostcode);`

Comment: You should not. $.ajax is capable of parsing JSON itself, use it.

Comment: No problem. FYI, the other answers are equally correct. You can set the datatype and jQuery will automagically call this method for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to tell javascript its a json object somehow?

Yes, you will need to tell it that it's a *json string*. Set the mimetype of your response to the appropriate "`application/json`", and jQuery's intelligence will parse the text automatically and call your `success` function with an object instead of a string.

Or you can set the `dataType` of your jQuery call to `"json"`, see the [`jQuery.ajax()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).